# What is the Schillerian concept for sublime that at the same time means attraction and repulsion?

Tags: metaphysics, aesthetics, idealism, german-philosophy

There is German word that Schiller uses to explain beauty, a word that at the same time means attraction and repulse.

He uses that word instead of the Kantian "awe" for The Sublime.

Does anyone knows what that word was?

Comment: Perhaps you mean *Spieltrieb*? Or simply the German word *Schönheit*?

Comment: Maybe useful : [F.Schiller:  “Concerning the Sublime” (*Über das Erhabene*)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schiller/#PathSublTrag)

Comment: @YechiamWeiss What does Spiel-trieb mean in Schiller's view? Does it mean both attraction and repulsion?

Comment: "Schiller resolves with the happy union of Formtrieb (the *the sensuous drive*) and Sinnestrieb (the *formal drive*), the '**play drive**', which for him is synonymous with artistic beauty, or 'living form'." From [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Friedrich_Schiller). It also acknowledged to be derived from the Critique of Judgment.